# Getting Nan loss in tensorflow when using softmax or sigmoid on output layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm having a problem when fitting a LSTM network in Keras with tensorflow as backend:

```
def build_recurrent(input_dim, output_dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(200,input_dim=input_dim,activation='tanh'))
    #model.add(Dense)
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(output_dim,activation='softmax'))
    return model
```

When I use softmax on the output layer (working with proportions) I get this:

```
Epoch 1/1500
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
Epoch 2/1500
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
Epoch 3/1500
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
Epoch 4/1500
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
Epoch 5/1500
0s - loss: nan - mean_squared_error: nan - mean_absolute_error: nan
```

while, when using another activation function, like for instance *tanh*:

```
Epoch 1/1500
0s - loss: 0.9173 - mean_squared_error: 0.9595 - mean_absolute_error: 0.9173
Epoch 2/1500
0s - loss: 1.0652 - mean_squared_error: 1.1457 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0652
Epoch 3/1500
0s - loss: 1.0652 - mean_squared_error: 1.1457 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0652
Epoch 4/1500
0s - loss: 1.0652 - mean_squared_error: 1.1457 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0652
Epoch 5/1500
0s - loss: 1.0652 - mean_squared_error: 1.1457 - mean_absolute_error: 1.0652
```

What kind of problem could it be? should I change the activation function of the hidden layer?

Another curious thing is that this happens just with the LSTM model, while when I use a simple feed-forward network I don't get any error